# nexus upload with maven-ant-resolver error invalid metadata doesn't match

Tags: maven, ant, nexus

I'm trying to use Ant to upload to a maven (nexus) repo, however am getting errrors.
Please see my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:resolver="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant">

   <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="path/to/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
   
   <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />

   <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant" resource="org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml">
      <classpath>
         <fileset dir="path/to/lib/" includes="maven-resolver-ant-tasks-1.4.0-uber.jar"/>
      </classpath>
   </taskdef>

   <property name="nexus_web" value="https://nexus.location.com/repository/location/item" />

   <resolver:authentication username="login-username" password="PASSWORD" id="auth"/>

   <resolver:remoterepo id="server" url="${nexus_web}">
      <resolver:releases enabled="true" checksums="warn"/>
      <resolver:authentication refid="auth"/>
   </resolver:remoterepo>

   <resolver:remoterepos id="all">
      <resolver:remoterepo refid="server"/>
   </resolver:remoterepos>

   <resolver:artifacts id="producedArtifacts">
      <resolver:artifact file="path/to/item/build/item/build/item-21-08-8.tar"/>
   </resolver:artifacts>

   <resolver:pom file="nexus-upload-pom.xml" id="pom"/>

   <target name="deploy">
      <resolver:deploy artifactsref="producedArtifacts">
         <resolver:remoterepo refid="server"/>
      </resolver:deploy>
   </target>
</project>
```

and my nexus-upload-pom.xml:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>testing</groupId>
   <artifactId>item</artifactId>
   <version>21-08-2</version>
   
   <name>item-name</name>
</project>
```

When I run this via 'ant deploy'

I get the following error:

```
deploy:
[resolver:deploy] Using default POM (testing:item:21-08-2)
[resolver:deploy] Uploading https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/21-08-2/item-21-08-2.pom
[resolver:deploy] Uploaded https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/21-08-2/item-21-08-2.pom (189 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
[resolver:deploy] Uploading https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/21-08-2/item-21-08-2.tar
[resolver:deploy] Uploaded https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/21-08-2/item-21-08-2.tar (347500 KB at 23231.7 KB/sec)
[resolver:deploy] Downloading https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/maven-metadata.xml
[resolver:deploy] Uploading https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item/testing/item/maven-metadata.xml

BUILD FAILED
path/to/item/build/nexus-upload.xml:34: Could not deploy artifacts: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata testing:item/maven-metadata.xml from/to dug (https://nexus.location.com/repository/testing-maven/item): status code: 400, reason phrase: Invalid maven-metadata.xml GAV testing, item, null does not match request path item/testing/item/maven-metadata.xml (400)

Total time: 16 seconds
```

As a kicker: there is no maven-metadata.xml on the sever at that location.
I'm trying to work out what is wrong with that section of the upload, is it an issue with what I've got in either of my configuration files (the null is a bit of a giveaway) or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: You have already a pom file why not using Maven to upload to Nexus?

Comment: .. because I want to use this in other projects that rely on Ant heavily

Comment: If you rely on Ant it's a bit out of date...furthermore that means you need to consume with Ant..which is easier with Maven... etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I had a hack around this morning following 'https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-Repo-2-' and still get the same error. So, with taking Ant out of the equation, have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reading on the intrawebs has led me to this trail:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19943
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-26419

With the workaround being:

```
nexus.maven.metadata.validation.enabled=false
```

Adding this property to data-dir/etc/nexus.properties
And then resetting nexus.